# Rename file in c#.net when its is uploaded through file upload control and save chang name of file in database

Tags: asp.net, database, file-upload, system, file-rename

I have file uploader through which i browse file 
and strore the name of of browse file in string variable .
now i want rename this uplaod file name with another name which stored in another string variable

```
string strRoleValue = ddlrole.SelectedValue;

 string strfilename = FileUpload1.FileName;
 string existpath = Server.MapPath("~\\JD\\");
 DirectoryInfo ObjSearchFile = new DirectoryInfo(existpath);
  string saveLocation = existpath + strfilename;
FileUpload1.SaveAs(saveLocation);
```

strRoleValue  this variable contains the name with which i want use to rename a file uploaded through fileupload.
filename uploaded through fileupload control stored in `strfilename`.
so before saving this file in specified folder
 i want to rename it with strRoleValue  value.
how can i achieve this..plz help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can check out the following link

http://asp-net-example.blogspot.in/2009/01/aspnet-fileupload-example-how-to-rename.html

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>  
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>  

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  

<script runat="server">  
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {  
        string uploadFolder = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "UploadFile\\";  
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)  
        {  
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);  
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(uploadFolder + "Test"+ extension);  
            Label1.Text = "File uploaded successfully as: " + "Test"+ extension;  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            Label1.Text = "First select a file.";  
        }  
    }  
</script>  

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head id="Head1" runat="server">  
    <title>asp.net FileUpload example: how to rename file when upload (change file name when upload)</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
    <form id="form1" runat="server">  
    <div>  
        <h2 style="color:Green">asp.net FileUpload example: File Rename</h2>  
        <asp:Label   
             ID="Label1"   
             runat="server"   
             Font-Size="Large"  
             ForeColor="OrangeRed"  
             >  
        </asp:Label>  
        <br /><br />  
        <asp:FileUpload   
             ID="FileUpload1"   
             runat="server"   
             BackColor="DeepPink"   
             ForeColor="AliceBlue"   
             />  
        <asp:Button   
             ID="Button1"   
             runat="server"   
             Font-Bold="true"   
             ForeColor="DeepPink"   
             OnClick="Button1_Click"  
             Text="Upload It"  
             />     
    </div>  
    </form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="fileUploadedButtonName" type="file" />
```

```
public ActionResult Register(HttpPostedFileBase fileUploadedButtonName){

 string newFileName= "";

 if (fileUploadedButtonName != null)
   {
     string path = HttpContext.Server.MapPath(@"~/YourFolderName");

     bool exists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(path);

     if (!exists)
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

     string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileUploadedButtonName.FileName);
     newFileName= Guid.NewGuid() + extension;
     string filePath = Path.Combine(path, newFileName);
     fileUploadedButtonName.SaveAs(filePath);

   }

}
```