# Change file name of FILE UPLOAD control

Tags: asp.net

This is my code:

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
    try
    {
        string file_name = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/FoodImage/1/") + file_name);
        Label1.Text = "File Upload";

    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Can not Upload File!";

    }
}
```

that code browse the for example "logo.jpg" and save in my server,but i want before to save change the file name,for example Browse button press and choose "logo.jpg" and click open then change the main file name "logo.jpg" to "L1.jpg" and save.

Comment: just save as a new file name does not work?

Comment: Yes, i change the file name and save but file can not open

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rename file in c#.net when its is uploaded through file upload control and save chang name of file in database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18095566/rename-file-in-c-net-when-its-is-uploaded-through-file-upload-control-and-save)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
//Check if user has selected a file and the file size is not 0
if (FileUpload1.HasFile && FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
{
   //Set the name you want for the file with no file extension
   string newFilename = "L1";

   //Get the file extension of the file being uploaded. 
   string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

   //Combine the new filename and the extension. You want to make sure it's the same file extension.
   string updatedFilename = newFilename + fileExtension;

   //Set the upload location
   string SaveLocation = Server.MapPath("~/FoodImage/1/");
   bool hasErrors = false;

   try
   {
       //Save the file to location with new filename
       FileUpload1.SaveAs(Path.Combine(SaveLocation + updatedFilename));
       hasErrors = false;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {  
       //Display error if any
       lblUploadStatus.Text = "Error uploading file. " + ex.Message.ToString();
       lblUploadStatus.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
       lblUploadStatus.Visible = true;
       hasErrors = true;
   }
   finally
   {
     //Do something or display success or failure

     if (hasErrors == false)
     {
       lblUploadStatus.Text = "File sucessfully uploaded with new filename: " + updatedFilename;
       lblUploadStatus.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
       lblUploadStatus.Visible = true;
     } 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`asp:FileUpload` gets rendered as `input type="file"` and it does not have that option. You can however do this simple workaround. That is, place a textbox below the `FileUpload` and prompt the user to enter the desired file name there.

Comment: dear friend ,i want get file name as database for example get "r_id" field and replace with main file name